# Handle null value for DateType in apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, databricks

Unable to handle the null value for date column in apache spark.
I tried replacing the null as an empty string as well as null value.

Error I am getting is 
`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""`

I am using csv-spark, databricks:spark-redshift_2.11 2.0.1

Code

`var originalDataFrame = sqlContext.load(
        "com.databricks.spark.csv",
        schema = sourceSchema,
        Map("path" -> filePath, 
            "header" -> "false",
            "codec"->"org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec",
            "delimiter"->"|",
            "dateFormat" -> dateFormat,
            "nullValue"->""
        ))`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how your are replacing the null value ? It can be done by na.fill(" ") while reading the file.Is this you are using ?

Comment: @NayanSharma added the code in the question.